# Multi threaded global object access

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading

Ok, I've a application which has two additional threads.

Thread one accesses object O and inserts data into a deque which is part of object O and increments a counter variable.

Thread two accesses object O and pulls out and deletes data from the deque and decrements the counter variable.

This turned out to give unexpected results since one thread tells me there are x elements inside of the deque and the other thread tells me there are no elements. I assume I have to use some kind of synchronization. I tried to use semaphore which I must have misunderstood since it didn't work ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686946(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686946%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

So I want to know how to access a global object from two threads. Be aware that the access to the global object O happens quite often since the access is within a while loop which results in continues insertions and polls. (Would the possible solution block the other thread from accessing the object and therefore the while loop?)

So far I only know of semaphore and mutex but have never used any of them, please be so kind and enlighten me.

Comment: Seems like you just described [the producer-consumer problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When accessing an object from multiple threads with one access possibly changing the object, you need some from of synchronization. For the scenario described you probably want to have a queue class which does the necessary thread protection and signalling. Here is a simple implementation:

```
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <deque>

template <typename T>
class queue
{
private:
    std::mutex              d_mutex;
    std::condition_variable d_condition;
    std::deque<T>           d_queue;
public:
    void push(T const& value) {
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(this->d_mutex);
            d_queue.push_front(value);
        }
        this->d_condition.notify_one();
    }
    T pop() {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(this->d_mutex);
        this->d_condition.wait(lock, [=]{ return !this->d_queue.empty(); });
        T rc(std::move(this->d_queue.back()));
        this->d_queue.pop_back();
        return rc;
    }
};
```

The code uses C++ 2011 constructs but it can easily be changed to avoid their use and rather use C++ 2003 constructs instead except that these aren't standardized.

The key points are:

1. A `std::mutex` is used to make sure only on thread accesses the queue at a time.
2. When putting something into the queue a lock on the mutex is acquired and the object is inserted into the queue. Once the object is inserted the lock is automatically released and a condition variable is signaled.
3. When extracting something from the queue a lock on the mutex is acquired and the thread waits for the queue to be non-empty using a condition variable: if there is something in the queue already, the condition will be `true` and `wait()` returns immediately, otherwise the thread is put to sleep until it gets a signal at which point the condition is reevaluated. Note, that the condition may be evaluated multiple times because there may be spurious wake-up to the condition variable.
4. The lambda captures its context by value: all it really captures is `this`; member variables cannot be captured directly because they are not part of the local context.
5. The result from `pop()` is returned by value: the moment the lock gets release, the container may be changed, making it impossible to return objects by reference, even if they were put into a suitable location.

The main reason this is somewhat of a toy example is that it doesn't have a nice way to shut down the system: If a thread is blocked on the queue it waits until there is another object. A real implementation would have some way to signal that it is time to shut down, possibly throwing an exception from `pop()`. Also, sometimes it is useful to have queue which doesn't force blocking to extract an object. Instead, it would have a function `try_pop()` which acquires a lock, checks if the queue is non-empty and depending on the result extracts and object or signals failure. A function like this is easy to implement, though.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to use `EnterCriticalSection`/`LeaveCriticalSection` around the code you want to use in an exclusive manner:

```
CRITICAL_SECTION critSect;

// Later in the code
EnterCriticalSection(&critSect);
// Do stuff with O
LeaveCriticalSection(&critSect);
```

You would of course use this in both threads. Only one thread can be inside the enter/leave zone at a time. The `EnterCriticalSection` will block until the other thread calls `LeaveCriticalSection`.